# Latex font color

Tags: latex, colors, fonts

I'm trying to typeset a document I'm working on.
Currently I'm trying to format a piece of text such that the text consists of two colors: a fill color and a line color. In this way the header should pop out more.

I found \psset with options such as linecolor and fillcolor, but I can't get it to work. Can someone provide an example of how I could do this?

Just providing a color using the color-package is no problem, but also not what I want because using this package I can only provide a single color for a piece of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for: [Contour package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/contour/). [Here's](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/contour/contour.pdf) the doc containing examples.